# Matplotlib Legend not showing on subplots

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I can't get the legends to show on the subplots which show up just fine and take the other formatting I've applied.  What am I missing?

If I do a plot for the dataframe alone, it shows the legend.  If I add a label to the plot for the subplots, it assigns that label to all three lines.

Here is image. plot vs subplot

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from functools import reduce

%matplotlib notebook

#Source for files
# Per Capita Personal Income
# Ann Arbor https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/ANNA426PCPI
# MI https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/MIPCPI
# USA https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/A792RC0A052NBEA

dfAnnArbor_PCPI = pd.read_csv('PerCapitaPersonalIncomeAnnArborMI.csv', skiprows=1, names=['Date', 'PCPI'])
dfMI_PCPI = pd.read_csv('PerCapitaPersonalIncomeMI.csv', skiprows=1, names=['Date', 'PCPI'])
dfUSA_PCPI = pd.read_csv('PerCapitaPersonalIncomeUSA.csv', skiprows=1, names=['Date', 'PCPI'])

# consolidate three df into one using Date
dfAll = [dfAnnArbor_PCPI, dfMI_PCPI, dfUSA_PCPI]
dfPCPI = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on='Date', how='outer'), dfAll)

dfPCPI = dfPCPI.dropna() # drop rows with NaN
dfPCPI.columns = ['Date', 'AnnArbor', 'MI', 'USA'] # rename columns
dfPCPI['Date'] = dfPCPI['Date'].str[:4] # select only year
dfPCPI = dfPCPI.set_index('Date')

dfPCPI_Rel = dfPCPI.apply(lambda x: x / x[0])

dfPCPI_Small = dfPCPI.iloc[8:].copy()
dfPCPI_SmRel = dfPCPI_Small.apply(lambda x: x / x[0])

dfPCPI_SmRel.plot()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)

ax0 = ax[0].plot(dfPCPI_Rel, '-', label='a')
ax1 = ax[1].plot(dfPCPI_SmRel, '-', label='test1')

ax[0].legend()

for x in fig.axes:
    for label in x.get_xticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(45)

ax[1].xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(2))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6):

The legend in pyplot refers to an axis instance. Therefore, if you want multiple plots to have their own legend, you need to call legend() for each axis. In your case

```
ax[0].legend()
ax[1].legend()
```

Additionally, as you are calling plot(), you may want to use the keyword label in each plot() call so as to have a label for each legend entry.

Answer (score 3):

You should try `fig.legend()` instead of `plt.legend()`